# Algoritmo para editar palabras con caracteres aleatorios de las mismas palabras en python

Tags: python

¿Qué debo editar de mi código para que esta función reciba una frase y devuelva una cadena con dos letras distintas elegidas al azar de cada palabra?

Tengo que hacer una función que reciba una frase y retorne una cadena formada por dos letras distintas elegidas al azar de cada palabra separadas por "_", las letras tienen que estar en el orden de aparición de la palabra.

```
Por ej: Entrada : abril mejor mes      Salida: BR_MO_ES
```

El problema que tengo es que mi código solo toma una palabra, no toma las tres, como puedo solucionarlo. Tengo esto hasta ahora:

```
import random
def separarfrase(entrada):
    l = entrada.split()
    return l
entrada = input("Frase:")
print(separarfrase(entrada))

def juntar(entrada):
    x = separarfrase(entrada)
    s = ""
    r = random.choice(x)
    cont = 0
    for elem in r:
        if cont < 2 and elem not in s:
            s = s + elem.upper() + "_"
        cont = cont + 1
    return s
print(juntar(entrada))
```

Comment: con r = random.choice(x) elijes una palabra debes recorrer la lista entrada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten cuidado porque si una palabra de la frase tiene una letra, fallaría. Se soluciona poniendo un if palabra < 2 y lo que quieras que haga en ese caso.

El fallo que tenías de porque te escogía solo una palabra es porque el random que haces es para escoger solo un elemento de entre todas las palabras que tiene la frase (cuando imagino que tu intención es escoger una de las letras que tiene la palabra).

Aun así seguiría dando fallo porque puede que te escoja primero la letra del final y después la del principio, por lo que se perdería el orden. Por eso decidí en mi código que el random sea sobre números que indiquen la posicion de la letra y después al final de cada palabra ordeno por orden esos dos números y luego extraigo la letra que corresponde.

```
import random

def elegir_letras(entrada):
    letras = ''
    for palabra in entrada:
        palabra = palabra.upper()
        cont = 0
        posiciones_escogidas=[]
        while cont <2:
            posicion_escogida = random.choice(range(len(palabra)))
            if posicion_escogida not in posiciones_escogidas:
                posiciones_escogidas.append(posicion_escogida)
                cont +=1
        letras = letras + palabra[sorted(posiciones_escogidas)[0]]+palabra[sorted(posiciones_escogidas)[1]]+'_'
    print(letras)


frase = input("Frase:").split(' ')
elegir_letras(frase)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias colega!!

Comment: a mandar compañero. Siempre aprendiendo. Me alegra que te guste mi respuesta

Answer (score 2):

casi lo tienes, mira esta función y compara:

```
def juntar(entrada):
    x = separarfrase(entrada)
    s = ""
    r = random.choice(x)
    for r in x:
        cont = 0
        for elem in r:
            if cont < 2 and elem not in s:
                s = s + random.choice(r).upper() + "_"
            cont = cont + 1
    return s
```

Mi solución final:

```
 def juntar(entrada):
    x = separarfrase(entrada)
    s = ""
    for r in x:
        if (len(r)>1):
                c=random.choice(r[:-1])
                s = s + c.upper() + "_"
                s = s + random.choice(r[1+r.index(c):]).upper() + "_"
        else:   s =s + r.upper()+ "_"
    return s[:-1]
```

He aquí un comportamiento útil en las operaciones de corte: s[:i] + s[i:] equivale a s.

palabra[:2]    # Los primeros dos caracteres

palabra[2:]    # Todos menos los primeros dos caracteres

palabra[-2:]    # Los dos últimos caracteres

palabra[:-2]    # Todos menos los dos últimos

Entonces:

r[:-1] es la palabra menos el ultimo carácter

r[1+r.index(c):]es la palabra a partir de la ocurrencia del caracter en *c* excluyendo *c*

**Con esto conseguimos elegir dos letras distintas que están en el orden de aparición en la palabra**(*salvo si hay caracteres repetidos en la palabra*) requisito del problema

```
def elimina_repes(palabra):
    f=str()
    i=0
    for c in palabra:
        if c not in palabra[:i]:f+=c
        i+=1

    return f
```

Valorar usar la funcion anterior que elimina letras repetidas manteniendo el orden p.e "acaba" => "acb"

Answer (score 1):

te dejo un codigo que te pueda gustar te lo expico para que lo puedas entender.
Según tengo entendido quieres que coja dos letras al azar de cada palabra separada por una "`_`" o por un espacio. ejemplo:
entrada:Mi llamo juan
salida:mi_lo_jn
te dejo un codigo que te puede servir:

```
import random
def frase(frase,caracter_separador):
 lista_de_frase=frase.split(caracter_separador)
 letras=str()
 for i in lista_de_frase:
  a=random.randrange(0,int(len(i)/2)) 
  b=random.randrange(int(len(i)/2)),len(i))
  letras=letras+i[a]
  letras=letras+i[b]
  letras=letras+"_"
 return letras
```

Con esto ahora prodras hacer esto.

```
a="me llamo juan"
b=frase(a," ")
print(b)
```

y te podria salir cualquier cosa al azar.

```
mm_ll_ja
me_lo_jn
```

es completamente al azar y te sale en orden.Asi se veria en un editor de código.
[image: asi se ve en un editor de codigo]
[image: y este es el resultado]

¿te fue util mi informacion?
por favor valorala:)